# Pentaho - Report does not show

Tags: mysql, pentaho

Hi all i have a web application in which i show a Pentaho Report. 
Now the report does not show anymore. 
I already checked that the user has the right to read the table.

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException: SELECT command denied to user 'sipac'@'TSIPAC02' for table 'servizio'
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelTag.doEndTag(OlapModelTag.java:86)
        at org.apache.jsp.jsp.Pivot_jsp._jspService(Pivot_jsp.java:889)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)

Caused by: com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapException: SELECT command denied to user 'sipac'@'TSIPAC02' for table 'servizio'
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.mondrian.MondrianModel.initialize(MondrianModel.java:557)
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.olap.model.OlapModelDecorator.initialize(OlapModelDecorator.java:132)
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelProxy$MyState.initialize(OlapModelProxy.java:77)
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.StackStateManager.initializeAndShow(StackStateManager.java:76)
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelProxy.initializeAndShow(OlapModelProxy.java:160)
        at com.tonbeller.jpivot.tags.OlapModelTag.doEndTag(OlapModelTag.java:81)
        ... 67 more

Answer (score 1):

How did you check that the user has the right? It gives an exact error about missing rights. That error is given by MySQL and not Pentaho, so this is missing rights.

Please run `GRANT SELECT ON [database].servizio TO 'sipac'@'TSIPAC02'` and `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

If you are sure that it has read rights, please login to mysql from TSIPAC02 server with user sipac, and ensure that the select works on the servizio table. Also ensure that you are using the same database as Pentaho.

Comment: Yes i can access to table with the user sipac.

Comment: [pentaho@tsipac02 ~]$  mysql --user=sipac --host=TSIPAC02 --password=**** sipac_sviluppo
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 201162

Comment: mysql> select * from servizio;    ---------------------+----------------------+----------------+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Comment: And you are sure that Pentaho also connects to `sipac_sviluppo` ?